# SMTP local server in windows 7? (running IIS7)

Tags: windows-7, iis-7, smtp, localhost

I'm trying to send a mail via python code via local SMTP server (localhost, port 25) in Windows 7 Enterprise edition. I'm obviously getting the irritating 
`[Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it` 
message, because I don't have any SMTP server installed. Because of Microsofts' ambigious documentation I thought that I can use the `Server manager` tool to install the local SMTP service, only to discover that it doesn't work on Windows 7.

I've read here in other threads that Windows 7 does not include the SMTP service anymore, so it doesn't have a local SMTP server. All threads directed the questioners to other, 3rd party SMTP services. The question is: is there any other way of configuring a local SMTP server yet? Or is it still an open issue, and I have no choice but to use a 3rd party software?

Answer (score 14):

This response is a little late, but might help the next person...

No, Windows 7 does not come with an SMTP server.  Supposedly Remote Server Administration tools includes an SMTP server, but according to this [link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/need-smtp-service-for-web-server-running-windows-7/87775bb7-707a-e011-9b4b-68b599b31bf5?msgId=ad12a3b2-797a-e011-9b4b-68b599b31bf5), it does not work.

Some options for sending email from a Windows 7 machine are:

For development purposes, I like smtp4dev https://github.com/rnwood/smtp4dev.  It is open source and emulates a SMTP server.  However instead of actually sending the email, it  keeps in in an app on the system tray.  Great for making sure you don't accidentally SPAM your users.

If you are planning to send emails out for real, I would advise using a SMTP server with a static IP address as most spam filters dislike dynamic addresses and will block the email.

I have not used it, but if you must send email from your local Windows machine and am not worried about SPAM filters, Free SMTP Server from www.softstack.com seems pretty popular.

[Edited link to new code repository]

Comment: smtp4dev is amazing! It will be one of my favorite from now on!

Comment: Thanks for the smtp4dev recommendation. It works really well.